# Python, Twisted and passing messages between protocols

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I understand there is already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807656/twisted-server-client-data-sharing) but as this is Server-to-Server rather than Server-to-Client is this really the only way?

I have a situation where "Computer A" connects to the "Server", port 5035 and opens a websocket. "Computer A" is a client in Twisted and will be sending messages to be processed.

"Computer B" connects to the same "Server", but different port 5025, different protocol and opens a websocket. "Computer B" is a client in Twisted but at a different protocol implementation.

From the examples I read...

"Computer A" sends a command to the "Server". The only way to initiate 'contact' with "Computer B" is to get the Server @ port 5035 to become a client of itself @ port 5025, send a message to itself so it can then be sent to "Computer B"?!

This is how I've approached it so far using Autobahn and Twisted:

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory, listenWS
from twisted.internet import task, reactor
from twisted.python import log
import sys

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

def onConnect(self, request):
    print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

def onOpen(self):
    print("WebSocket connection open.")

def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    if isBinary:
        print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
    else:
        print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))
        processMessage(self, payload.decode('utf8'), isBinary)

def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
    print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

def processMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    a = payload.split(':')

    if len(a) > 1:
        token = a[0].strip()
        command = a[1].strip()
        content = a[2].strip()

        msg = ""

        if command == "iam":
            print "message: " + content
            msg = payload

        else:
            print("Invalid command!")

        if isBinary:
            # something wrong?
            print("ERROR! Binary data!")
        else:
            print 'ready to send'
            # need to send this to the client connected to MyServerProtocol2 !!!!!!!!   
            # somehow I need to call MyServerProtocol2.sendMessageToClient ??????


class MyServerProtocol2(WebSocketServerProtocol):

def onConnect(self, request):
    print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

def onOpen(self):
    print("WebSocket connection open.")

def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    if isBinary:
        print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
    else:
        print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
    print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))

def sendMessageToClient(self, ):
    self.sendMessage(msg.encode('utf8'), isBinary)



if __name__ == '__main__':

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:5035", debug=False)
factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
reactor.listenTCP(5035, factory)

factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://locahlhost:5025", debug=False)
factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol2
reactor.listenTCP(5025, factory)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: @Jean-Paul I don't think is a duplicate unless as I describe I have to go a long way around to get a message from A to B?

Comment: Take a closer look at the other question and answer.  It's not the exact situation you have but it's very similar and the answer is just as applicable here.  Be sure to read the English words and not just the code.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Paul ! I have gone down another path and use the same port & factory for both Computers and 'route' messages and responses appropriately but what you mention makes sense and might be a good idea to update the FAQ with your examples as well.