# Writing a p2p client/server app

Tags: python, twisted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a twisted server that is also a client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275004/how-to-write-a-twisted-server-that-is-also-a-client)

How can I create a tcp client server app with twisted, where also the server can send requests, not just answer them? Sort of like a p2p app but where clients always initiate the connection. Since I don't know when the requests from the server will occur, I don't see how I can do this once the reactor is started.

Answer (score 1):

The question you have to ask yourself is: why is the server sending a request?

Presumably something has happened in the world that would prompt the server to send a request; it wouldn't just do it at random.  Even if it did it at random, the thing that has happened in the world would be "some random amount of time has passed".  In other words, `callLater(random(...), doSomething)`.

When you are writing a program with Twisted, you start off by setting up ways to react to events.  Then you run the reactor - i.e. the "thing that reacts to events" - forever.  At any time you can set up new ways to react to incoming network events (`reactor.connectTCP`, `reactor.listenTCP`, `reactor.callLater`) or tear down existing waiting things (`protocol.loseConnection`, `port.stopListening`, `delayedCall.cancel`).  You don't need to re-start the reactor; in fact, really, the only thing you should do before the reactor runs is do `reactor.callWhenRunning(someFunctionThatListensOrConnects)`, and write `someFunctionThatListensOrConnects` to do all your initial set-up.  That set-up then happens once the reactor is already running, which demonstrates that you don't need to do anything in advance; the reactor is perfectly capable of changing its configuration as it runs.

If the event that causes the server to send an event to client B the fact that client A sent it a message, then your question is answered by the FAQ, "[how do I make input on one connection result in output on another?](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother)"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand a lot better now, but it leads me to another question: How can I have an event that is not network related, like some user input or a pressed button?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.  Be sure to ask it specifically with regards to what GUI toolkit you're using.