# python twisted client server in one thread

Tags: python, asynchronous, client-server, twisted

I have modified Jean-Paul Calderone's code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275944/769384) to achieve that two server are run asynchronously in one thread and the second server is the client of the first one (he's a broker). This is my current code:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic

class BaseServerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.sendLine("I can see that you said: %s" % (line,))
        self.transport.loseConnection()

##############################################################

class BrokerServerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        factory = protocol.ClientFactory()
        factory.protocol = BrokerClientProtocol
        reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 12345, factory)
        self.sendLine("I did connect but have nothing to return")
        # TODO: return broker client's response

class BrokerClientProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Hello!")
        # TODO: receive the message from broker
        self.transport.loseConnection()

##############################################################

def main():
    import sys
    from twisted.python import log

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = BaseServerProtocol
    reactor.listenTCP(12345, factory)

    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = BrokerServerProtocol
    reactor.listenTCP(12346, factory)

    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I would like to modify here is to replace both `# TODO` lines - first, I'd like to fetch BaseServer's response by the BrokerClient (second todo) and then fetch it by the BrokerServer (which has just created the BrokerClient, first todo). Can anyone help?